# iOS stock Location icon or UIButton/UIBarButtonItem style?

Tags: ios, uibutton, mkmapview, uibarbuttonitem, uibarbuttonitemstyle

Does `iOS` come with a stock "location" icon or `UIButton`/`UIBarButtonItem` style?

I'd rather not have to include a separate `png` just for this... So I'd like to know if there's a stock "location" `UIButton`/`UIBarButtonItem` style, similar to the stock "add/trash/search" button styles.

I'm looking for this "location" icon:
[image: LocationIcon]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I am aware, you will have to include it yourself. I don't think this is a publicly accessible image on the iOS SDK.